# Printing all accidentals with Lilypond

Tags: lilypond, accidentals, engraving

I am trying to print all the accidentals within a staff (or within the score, both would work) while engraving with Lilypond. Currently, it's because I'm engraving 80+ bar, multi-staff unmetered music with a lot of accidentals, and the original partition shows all the accidentals. I know I can add `!` to force it, but I don't want to do it manually for all the accidentals. Is there a way to do so ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lilypond has several options to [automatically display accidentals](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/displaying-pitches#automatic-accidentals). I'm not sure which one suits you best, but perhaps one of these:

> `teaching`
>
> This rule is intended for students, and makes it easy to create scale sheets with automatically created cautionary accidentals. Accidentals are printed like with `modern`, but cautionary accidentals are added for all sharp or flat tones specified by the key signature, except if the note is immediately repeated.
>
> [image]

> `forget`
>
> This is the opposite of `no-reset`: Accidentals are not remembered at all – and hence all accidentals are typeset relative to the key signature, regardless of what came before in the music.
>
> [image]